# Set values of object properties with different types from formcollection values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have to set object values with different types from FormCollection values. I have this method:

```
public void EditProduct(string category, FormCollection formCollection) //Edit choosen product.
    {
        var product = GetNewProduct(category);
        var EfContext = GetEfContext(category);
        foreach (var property in product.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var NewValue = formCollection[property.Name];
            property.SetValue(product, NewValue);
        }
        EfContext.GetType().GetMethod("EditProduct").Invoke(EfContext, new object[] { product });
    }
```

But I get errors about converting from string to other type in object. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was `Convert.ChangeType()` method.

```
public void EditProduct(string category, FormCollection formCollection) //Edit choosen product.
    {
        var product = GetNewProduct(category);
        var EfContext = GetEfContext(category);
        foreach (var property in product.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var NewValue = Convert.ChangeType(formCollection[property.Name], property.PropertyType);
            property.SetValue(product, NewValue);
        }
        EfContext.GetType().GetMethod("EditProduct").Invoke(EfContext, new object[] { product });
    }
```